# Why everything in nav bar display in column?Even the img element take up a hole line

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Img and span element display in two lines without any css. Is this because of inherit?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Manage your account</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="sticky w-full h-14 top-0 left-0 bg-red-100 border-b">
        <div class="w-[1280px] mx-auto flex justify-between items-center">
            <div class=" place-content-center">
                <img src="tailwindcss-ar21.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <div class=" none ml-7 place-content-center">
                    <img src="user avatar.jpg" alt="" height="32px" width="32px">
                 </div>
                <div class=" place-content-center"><a href="" class="font-bold">Settings</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

The important one. I think the error kind related to inherit,so I paste the code above

```
        <nav class="sticky top-14 w-40 bg-indigo-100">
            <div>
                <img src="./user avatar.jpg" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"><span>tabone</span> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="./user avatar.jpg" alt="" width="32px" height="32px"><span>tabtwo</span>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <article>
            
        </article>
    </section>    
</body>
</html>
```

[in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF44F.png)

Everything in nav bar display in column. Even the img and span. The img and span are inline element.

Why does these element display in one line? The span start a new line.

I tried flex attribute and give it a flex-direction: column.It didn't work.

I tried attach the inline-block value to img element, still didn't work.

Comment: `div` elements are `block` level by default - you have not shown any CSS that controls the properties of DIV elements - each DIV will occupy a line

Comment: I use tailwind css， therefor CSS is just in the element. I mean the img and span didn't show in one line .

Answer (score 0):

Using just "flex" attribute is not enough. You have to specify the direction; it should have been flex-row instead of flex-column.

Check this snippet, it will display img and span in one line :
https://play.tailwindcss.com/M6JA6zMdol